# Allow EPiServer user to change or reset password

Tags: passwords, episerver

We have a lot of external users to one of our site. They register themselves, and we store the external users with the SQLMembership provider. Internal users (admins) are handled using WindowsMembership.

A standard part of having an account is to be able to reset or change ones own password. Is there a standard EPiServer way of allowing that? I have not found any so far, but it seems strange that every developer should implement that on their own...

Both out of the box-solutions and third party modules are welcome, as well as home grown solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a drop down at the top right of the editor navigation showing the current logged in username, in that, click "My Settings"

The direct url would be %pathtoepiserver%/CMS/edit/mysettings.aspx

e.g

/episerver/CMS/edit/mysettings.aspx

EDIT:

Just realised you said external users, not CMS editors. There's no built in way with EPiServer, but the logins use ASP.Net membership system, which has its own controls and templates for common membership functions.

This article might be of assistance:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/admin/recovering-and-changing-passwords-cs